# mAP scores on tensorboard (Tensorflow Object Detection API) are all 0 even though the loss value is low

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I trained a faster-rcnn model on the tensorflow object detection API on a custom dataset. I found that the loss is ~2 after 3.5k steps. However, when I ran eval.py, the mAP scores are all almost 0 as shown below.

[image: Category-wise mAP scores on Tensorboard]

I do not understand why this is the case. However, when I look at the images at 3.5k steps, the model has captured some of the boxes as shown below

[image: output of the Faster-RCNN model after 3.5k iterations]

Can someone please explain why the mAP scores are close to zero, even though the model has learned to output quite a few boxes?

Answer (score 7):

I recommend several checks to make sure you get reasonable mAP@IoU scores for object detection API:

1. Try varying the Intersection over Union (IoU) threshold, e.g 0.2-0.5 and see if you get an increase in average precision. You would have to modify `matching_iou_threshold` parameter in `object_detection/utils/object_detection_evaluation.py`
2. Try different evaluator classes (the default one is `EVAL_DEFAULT_METRIC = 'pascal_voc_detection_metrics'`). If you are training on [Open Image Dataset](https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/index.html) it makes sense to use `open_images_V2_detection_metrics`
3. Check your eval config file and increase the number of examples used in the evaluation set, e.g.

   `eval_config: {
     num_examples: 20000
     num_visualizations: 16
     min_score_threshold: 0.2
     # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
     # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
     max_evals: 1
   }`
4. Train the object detector for more iterations
5. Check current mAP against reported metrics (e.g. COCO mAP@IoU=0.5):
   [image: COCO mAP at IoU=0.5]

Comment: however the  tensorflow official page  suggest to install COCO API from  <path_to_tensorflow>/models/research/ did you find any solution ?????https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md